# What's happening on RoR server - OpenUri / link_to remote: true

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need call some php script from Rails application and I would like to know what's happening  on server and what's the best choice to run this php script when I ..

Call the php script like this:

`= link_to('Run', 'http://domain.tld/myscript.php', remote: true)`

or link to some action where is:

`open('http://domain.tld/myscript.php)`

I think the best option is link_to. When I use open, it's waiting for response..
PHP script runs about 30 minutes..

Now I use open and delayed_job, but I think link_to is less demanding on the server.

Thanks

Comment: Don't put spaces between your method name and opening bracket. Use either `link_to "run", ...` or `link_to("run"...)`, but never `link_to ("run"...)`. It actually *does* matter.

Comment: On a side note, 30 minutes? What exactly does it do? Is there any way to speed that up?

Comment: I'm sorry, I use link_to(..), my mistake.
Yes, about 30 minutes. It's updating lot of products, I have my own server, that's no problem. But I would like run it from my application and not via url/cron

Comment: I think it can be faster, when I send more products in one SOAP request, but I don't know how right now.

Comment: I rewrote API to Ruby and now everything works great. And it's running on backend with Sidekiq